# any is not assignable to parameter of type (response: Response) => any

Tags: angular, typescript

On my mean stack project I am trying to display the contents within my database onto a table on my html page.

Here is a sample record from my database i made on mlab:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5befa2ad59ef330bc8568373"
    },
    "player": "loco",
    "rank": 1,
    "score": 200,
    "time": "1d 2hrs",
    "gamesPlayed": "League",
    "status": "online",
    "__v": 0
}
```

This information should be displayed in my table like this:

Player.component.html:

```
<tr>
<td>Player</td>
<td>Rank</td>
<td>Score</td>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Games Played</td>
<td>Status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{player.name}}</td>
<td>{{player.rank}}</td>
<td>{{player.score}}</td>
<td>{{player.time}}</td>
<td>{{player.gamesPlayed}}</td>
<td>{{player.status}}</td>
</tr>                          //For each player create new row on table displaying player info
```

Im unable to figure out how to display player info for every player i have on my database.

### -

-
The work i have done so far is this:

I created a service file player.service.ts

On this file im getting an error that says: 
Argument of type '(response: import("myapp/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response").Response) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(response: Response) => any'.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayerService {

  private _getUrl = "/api/players";

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }  //instance of http to make requests

  getPlayers()
  {
    return this._http.get(this._getUrl)           //call get method passing the url and fetch all players
    .map((response: Response)=> response.json());  //response is mapped to json
  }
}
```

### -

-
On my player.component.ts file everything is running smoothly:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from '../player';
import { PlayerService } from '../player.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player-center',
  templateUrl: './player-center.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-center.component.css'],
  providers: [PlayerService]
})
export class PlayerCenterComponent implements OnInit {

  players: Array<Player>; //players is array of type player

  selectedPlayer: Player;

  constructor(private _playerService: PlayerService) { }  //dependancy injection to get playerservice

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this._playerService.getPlayers()
    .subscribe(resPlayerData => this.players = resPlayerData);
  }

  onSelectPlayer(player:any)
  {
    this.selectedPlayer = player;
    console.log(this.selectedPlayer);
  }

}
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error on player.service.ts??
And some help on how I can get all my players into the table on my html page would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to import HttpClientModule In app.module to resolve the Error 'NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!'

```
export class AppModule {
   imports: [
     HttpClientModule
   ]
}
```

You could try your service like : (you dont need to parse to json)

```
getPlayers(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this._getUrl);
}
```

Then, in your template :

```
  <tr *ngFor="let player of players">
    <td>{{player.name}}</td>
    <td>{{player.rank}}</td>
    <td>{{player.score}}</td>
    <td>{{player.time}}</td>
    <td>{{player.gamesPlayed}}</td>
    <td>{{player.status}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @James is that not the correct answer? if so please explain why. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but i had to install rxjs and then import observable as it was giving me an error on observable. But now when i run the project i am getting this error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PlayerService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PlayerService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!

Comment: @james as per the error suggest -  you need to remove `providers: [PlayerService]` from your component since you have used `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` you service will be injected to your `AppModule` so you don't need to add providers again in your component - My suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

On first case you are using a deprecated version of `http` if in case you upgrade your angular you need to use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` for more details check this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

Finally there is no need of mentioning the response type you can directly convert it as `json()` as my thought

```
getPlayers()
{
  return this._http.get(this._getUrl)           
    .map((response)=> response.json()); 
}
```

This will be fine to work your code - hope this helps you - happy coding :)

**Update:**

For rxjs 6+ you need to use the operators in different manner

`import { map, pipe } from 'rxjs/operators'` first change in import statement

```
getPlayers() : Observable<Players[]>
    {
      return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
       .pipe(map((response)=> response.data)); 
    }
```

Try something like this for more info check [this](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/) - hope it helps :)

Comment: When i try running the project it fails to compile with the following error: 
ERROR in src/app/player.service.ts: error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Comment: What `rxjs` version you are using ?

Comment: I am using version 6.3.3

Comment: For rxjs 6+ the operators are changed little bit - i will update my code please try

Comment: Ok now on my player.component.ts the ngOnInit() function gives me error at 
.subscriber(resPlayerData => this.players = resPlayerData);
Error: type 'Response' is not assignable to type Player[]

Comment: Okay i missed the `response.data` add it in your service and mention your return type that might help you for any conversation - if you didn't receive data as `Players[]` mention it as `any` to get the array value - it's better to use angular upgraded version or rxjs lower version which supports `map` instead of pipe in your case :) - make sure you have sync with your rxjs and angular versions :)